# After selector change doesn't change

Tags: jquery

I try to edit the value of a css selector :after, but it won't work in jQuery

```
$('.triangle-right.left:after').css("border-color","transparent #fff");
```

What to do?

CSS:

```
.triangle-right.left:after {
 top:4px; 
 left:-10px; /* value = - border-left-width - border-right-width */
 bottom:auto;
 border-width:15px 15px 0 0; /* vary these values to change the angle of the vertex */
 border-color:transparent #bdd5bb; 
}
```

I want to change the border-color in javascript.
HTML:

```
document.getElementById('canvas').innerHTML += "<div id='talkbubble-" + u + "' style='display:none;color:#000;position:absolute;left:" + (left +9) + "px;top:" + (top + 1) + "px;z-index:" + (z + 95) + "'>" +

"<p class='triangle-right left' id='text_"+u+"' style=\"color:#0d0e0c;background:#bdd5bb;\"></p>" + 
"</DIV>";
```

Javascript/jQuery:

```
 $('#text_'+u).css("color","#000");
           $('.triangle-right.left').next().css("border-color","transparent #fff");


           $('#text_'+u).css("color","#0d0e0c");
           $('#text_'+u).css("background","#fff");



              $('#text_' + u).html(sockb.data.text);

      $('#talkbubble-' + u).fadeIn();

                  tDelays[u] = setTimeout(function () {
                      $('#talkbubble-' + u).fadeOut(function () {
                          $('#text_' + u).html("");
                          delete tDelays[u];
                      });
                  }, 15000);
```

Comment: There's no `:after` selector.

Answer (score 0):

Try with .**next**() like

```
$('.triangle-right.left').next().css("border-color","transparent #fff");
```

And try this [**LINK**](http://api.jquery.com/next/) There is no selector like :**after**

Comment: Seems like it still not works. It should only work in a <div outside called "talkbubble_tester" so how is it working? $('.triangle-right.left > #talkbubble_tester').next().css("border-color","transparent #fff"); ?

Answer (score 0):

`:after` is not a selector, but a pseudo-selector. As such, it is not part of the DOM and cannot be accessed by Javascript.